Terraform creating duplicate Route 53 zones
Github Repo : https://github.com/dongkoony/BootGenie_AWS_Terraform
I'm using Terraform to provision AWS resources and have organized my setup into modules. The resources I'm creating include EC2, VPC, ALB, CloudFront, WAFv2, and Route 53. Here is a brief overview of my directory structure and the main.tf file
Directory Structure:
.
├── modules
│   ├── acm
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── alb
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── cloudfront
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── ec2
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── jenkins
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── route53
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── vpc
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── wafv2
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── script
│   ├── app_instance_docker.sh
│   ├── change_ssh_port.sh
│   ├── get_jenkins_password.sh
│   └── jenkins_container.sh
├── .gitignore
├── .terraform.lock.hcl
├── jenkins.tf
├── LICENSE
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── README.md
├── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── terraform.tfvars
└── variables.tf

main.tf:
provider "aws" {
  region = local.region
}

locals {
  region      = "ap-northeast-2"
  domain_name = "donghyeonporfol.site"
}

# VPC module
module "vpc" {
  source              = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_name            = var.vpc_name
  vpc_cidr            = var.vpc_cidr
  availability_zones  = var.availability_zones
  public_subnet_cidrs = var.public_subnet_cidrs
  private_subnet_cidrs = var.private_subnet_cidrs
}

# ALB module (initially HTTP only)
module "alb" {
  source      = "./modules/alb"
  name_prefix = var.name_prefix
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnets     = module.vpc.public_subnet_ids
  certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.selected.arn
  tags        = var.tags
}

# EC2 module
module "ec2" {
  source = "./modules/ec2"

  name_prefix                 = var.name_prefix
  ami                         = var.ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_id                      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_rules               = var.ingress_rules
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  user_data                   = var.user_data
  root_volume_size            = var.root_volume_size
  tags                        = var.tags

  availability_zones          = var.availability_zones
  subnet_id                   = module.vpc.public_subnet_ids

  app_instance_count          = var.app_instance_count
  web_instance_count          = var.web_instance_count

  web_target_group_arn        = module.alb.web_target_group_arn
  app_target_group_arn        = module.alb.app_target_group_arn

  depends_on                  = [module.alb]
}

# Route 53 module
module "route53" {
  source         = "./modules/route53"
  domain_name    = local.domain_name
  alb_dns_name   = module.alb.alb_dns_name
  alb_zone_id    = module.alb.alb_zone_id
  depends_on     = [module.alb, module.ec2]
}

# ACM certificate creation and validation
module "acm" {
  source         = "./modules/acm"
  domain_name    = local.domain_name
  route53_zone_id = module.route53.zone_id  # Route53 module must output zone_id
  ttl            = var.ttl
  depends_on     = [module.route53]
}

# Add ALB HTTPS listener
resource "aws_lb_listener" "https" {
  load_balancer_arn = module.alb.alb_arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = module.acm.acm_certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = module.alb.web_target_group_arn
  }

  depends_on = [module.acm]
}

# <-------------------------------WAFv2 testing------------------------------->
# WAF module
# module "waf" {
#   source = "./modules/wafv2"
#   waf_prefix            = var.waf_prefix
#   waf_ip_sets           = var.waf_ip_sets
#   managed_rules         = var.managed_rules
#   environment           = var.environment
#   project               = var.project
#   waf_ip_set_name       = "default-ip-set"
#   waf_ip_set_description = "Default IP set for WAF"
#   waf_ip_set_addresses  = var.waf_ip_sets
#   waf_web_acl_name      = "${var.waf_prefix}-web-acl"
#   waf_web_acl_description = "Web ACL for ${var.waf_prefix}"
#   waf_web_acl_metric_name = "${var.waf_prefix}-metric"
#   scope                 = "CLOUDFRONT"
#   tags                  = var.tags
# }

# CloudFront module
# module "cloudfront" {
#   source = "./modules/cloudfront"
#   origin_domain_name = var.origin_domain_name
#   origin_id          = var.origin_id
#   target_origin_id   = var.target_origin_id
#   web_acl_id         = module.waf.web_acl_arn  # Using WAF module's web ACL ARN
#   environment        = var.environment
#   project            = var.project
# }

The problem I'm encountering is that the Route 53 zone is being created twice. Once initially and then another time after the EC2 instances are created, resulting in two Route 53 zones.
I'm considering creating a separate route53.tf file and running terraform apply again after all the resources are created. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.
I expected the Route 53 zone to be created only once. However, it is being created twice - once initially and then again after the EC2 instances are created.
Questions:

Why is the Route 53 zone being created twice?
Is separating the Route 53 configuration into its own .tf file and applying it afterward a good practice?
How can I ensure that the Route 53 zone is only created once without having to run terraform apply twice?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Your main.tf code posted here looks alright. But it doesn't seem to be the same as the one in your repo.
Going by the one in your repo, the R53 hosted zone is being created twice because you've defined the code to create it twice: once by calling aws_route53_zone directly, and another by calling the R53 module.
From your repo, see the 2 instances where it's happening:

https://github.com/dongkoony/BootGenie_AWS_Terraform/blob/master/main.tf#L13-L15

https://github.com/dongkoony/BootGenie_AWS_Terraform/blob/master/main.tf#L101-L107


You will want to create the hosted zone first before the ACM (which depends on the hosted zone)
Terraform stores the state of the infrastructure as defined by your code in the state file. It's not possible that it creates the same resource twice unless you have explicitly defined in your code.
